# How to select with css_selector selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I have the right code just its taking very long time until its selecting a random month. It goes all options through to find that option. Any way to make it faster?

Tried:

```
randomMonth = random.choice(["Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez"])
for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
    if i.text == randomMonth:
        i.click()
```

Login Page from Payoneer.com Datepicker Month selection

```
<select class="ui-datepicker-month" data-handler="selectMonth" data-event="change">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Jan</option>
    <option value="1">Feb</option>
    <option value="2">Mar</option>
    <option value="3">Apr</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">Jun</option>
    <option value="6">Jul</option>
    <option value="7">Aug</option>
    <option value="8">Sep</option>
    <option value="9">Oct</option>
    <option value="10">Nov</option>
    <option value="11">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I could not find the Datepicker on login page. Can you please share the html of the list box. The loop should target particular list > option rather just with all options on the page.

Comment: Added the html somehow its one line, hopefully you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were close. There is a helper class to make dealing with `SELECT` elements easier. You can use the `Select` class and choose the exact one you want without looping.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
...
randomMonth = random.choice(["Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez"])
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ui-datepicker-month"))
select.select_by_visible_text(randomMonth)
```

NOTE: You may have to adjust the CSS selector I chose if you have a lot of `SELECT` elements on the page but the basics on picking a random month and then selecting that from a dropdown should get you pointed in the right direction.

See [the python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) for more information about the `Select` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its giving me this now "AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'select_by_text'"

Comment: @VRX I typo'd it... it's fixed now. It should have been `select_by_visible_text()`.